# could not detect boost libraries when running ./configure when compiling bitcoin core code

Tags: boost, bitcoin

This is the error I get:

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.58.0 (105800)... configure: 
We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.58.0 or higher). 
If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  
If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
configure: error: Boost is not available!
```

I am on the latest version of macOS big sur and I installed boost with homebrew. I believe boost should be installed in usr/local/include, but for me, it is installed in /opt/homebrew/opt/boost. Could this be the issue? I used a symlink to go from usr/local/include to /opt/homebrew/opt/boost but it didn't work when I cded into the bitcoin folder and then ran ./configure.

Comment: What if you run `export BOOST_ROOT=/opt/homebrew/opt/boost` before building?

Comment: `config.log` contains a copy of the configure script's diagnostic output. You can locate, in this log file, the test program that the `configure` script attempted to compile in order to detect the availability of the boost libraries. Based on that it should be possible to determine the reason for the compilation failure, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    export BOOST_ROOT=/opt/homebrew/opt/boost
    ./configure --with-gui=no --without-bdb --with-boost=$BOOST_ROOT
```

Your options may differ

Comment: this worked for me in macos `./configure --prefix=$PWD/depends/arm-apple-darwin20.2.0 --with-boost=$BOOST_ROOT`

Comment: worked as listed with centos 7

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but... For those who own MacBook with ARM architecture (or Apple silicon).

1. First of all you should install boost library with Homebrew - `brew install boost`
2. then let's find path to the installed library. Type `brew info boost`.
3. You can see something like: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.84.0`
4. Run configuration script with argument:

`./configure --with-boost="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.84.0"`

5. Profit!